# IMEI validation java convert string to long losing leading 0

Tags: java, imei

I am trying to validate IMEI numbers using the code below, the user will enter their number on a page and this then runs `isValidIMEI` using a string that is converted to a long.

Now this does work for almost all IMEI's that I have come across but for a few iPhone 5's they have a leading 0, so 0133xxxxxxxxxx0 for example. When this is casted to a long the leading 0 is lost so it becomes 14 digits and fails, if I turn off the length checker this still won't work as it will be doubling the wrong digits.

Any idea how I can convert to some kind of number format but keep that leading 0?

```
/**
 * Sum digits
 *
 * @param n
 * @return
 */
private static int sumDig(int n)
{
    int a = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        a = a + n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return a;
}

/**
 * Is valid imei
 *
 * @param n
 * @return
 */
public boolean isValidIMEI(long n)
{
    // Converting the number into String
    // for finding length
    String s = Long.toString(n);
    int len = s.length();

    Log.v("IMEIValidation", s);

    if (len != 15) {
        Log.v("IMEIValidation", "Length issue");
        return false;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = len; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        int d = (int)(n % 10);

        // Doubling every alternate digit
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            d = 2 * d;

        // Finding sum of the digits
        sum += sumDig(d);
        n = n / 10;
    }

    Log.v("IMEIValidation", String.valueOf(sum));


    Log.v("IMEIValidation", String.valueOf(sum % 10));
    return (sum % 10 == 0);
}
```

Comment: "using a string that is converted to a long." - imo that's the error. Just don't convert ids that are strings to numbers even if they only contain digits. Keep treating them as strings and check the individual characters. To calculate the checksum you'd then convert each character to a single number and do the calculation based on that.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan, but when I convert a string of "0" to a long will it remain as 0?

Comment: If you convert the _character_ `'0'` to a number (`int` would be sufficient and the most natural type to use in Java calculations) you'll of course get the value 0. The check for a digit would be `Character.isDigit()` and the conversion could be done as `c - '0'`.

Comment: Fantastic, trying that now